# Is NHibernate faster than a classic ODBC Driver?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, odbc

I am working on an application with a kinda simple data model (4 tables including two small, having around 10 rows, and two bigger, having hundreds of rows).
I'm working with C# and currently use an OdbcDriver for my Data Access Layer.
I was wondering if there is any difference in terms of performance between this driver or NHibernate?
The application works but I'd like to know if installing NHibernate instead of a classic OdbcDriver would make it faster? If so, is the difference really worth installing NHibernate? (according to the fact that I have never used such technology)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any performance problems with Odbc? And what are you planning to do? NHibernate is an O/RM tool, not a database driver. You can't just switch from one to another.

Comment: I was thinking about switching to NHibernate but I feared that it was actually slower than the current system, which seems to be the case according to everybody's answer. I will finally consider switching DB driver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: no, NHibernate will actually slow your performance in most cases.

Longer answer: NHibernate uses the basic ADO.NET drivers, including OdbcConnection (if there's nothing better), to perform the actual SQL queries. On top of that, it is using no small amount of reflection to digest queries into SQL, and to turn SQL results into lists of objects. This extra layer, as flexible and powerful as it is, is going to perform more slowly than a hard-coded "firehose" solution based on a DataReader.

Where NHibernate may get you the APPEARANCE of faster performance is in "lazy-loading". Say you have a list of People, who each have a list of PhoneNumbers. You are retrieving People from the database, just to get their names. A naive DataReader-based implementation may involve calling a stored procedure for the People that includes a join to their PhoneNumbers, which you don't need in this case. Instead, NHibernate will retrieve only People, and set a "proxy" into the reference to the list of PhoneNumbers; when the list needs to be evaluated, the proxy object will perform another call. If the phone number is never needed, the proxy is never evaluated, saving you the trouble of pulling phone numbers you don't need.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very useful set on information! I was thinking by pure logic that NHibernate should be slower, you just confirmed my fears, I'll switch to another strategy then

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate isn't about making it faster and it'll alwasy be slower than just using the database primatives like you are (it uses them "under the hood").

In my opinion NHibernate about making a **reusable** entity layer that can be applied to different applications or at the very least reused in multiple areas in one medium to large application. Therefore moving your application to NHibernate would be a waste of time (it sounds very small).

You might get better performance by using a specific datbase driver for your database engine.

Comment: It is a waste of time indeed, thank you for bringing up that point, I'll consider another approach :)

Answer (score 1):

For amount of data in your database it won't make any difference. But in general using NHibernate will slow down application performance, but increase development speed. But this is generally true for all ORM's.

Comment: Your statement isn't true at all. NHibernate and ORMs will actually have an effect on development speed but won't necessarily speed it up compared to just using ADO.NET. With an ORM you've got to learn the framework and it's limitiations and craft your entites then use them to get the data. You don't have to do that with ADO.NET. The second time you use your entites it might be a bit faster to develop but not a lot. The benifit is in consistancy of your model and logic.

Answer (score 0):

SOme hint: NHIbernate is not magic. It sits on top of ADO.NET. Want a faster driver? GET ONE. Why are yo using a slow outdated technilogy like ODbc anyway? WHat is your data source? Don't they support ANY newer standard like OLEDB?

Comment: The app works with a MySQL Database. I just started working on that project, which was initially done by a trainee who used ODBC for database connection. Now that the DB is bigger than the one he used, queries start to take more than 3 seconds, I am trying to lower the time and to refactor his code (I wanted to use NHibernate because I used EclipseLink with Java and found it very easy to understand). The MySql driver unfortunately does not seem to be available for .NET 4, do you have any advice?

Comment: Ok, two things: (a) he should have used OleDb and (b) THE DRIVER DONT CHANGE THE DATABASE. You pull in a million rows, the driver sont make it magically faster. The server takes an hour to process a bad query - again, the driver wont make it faster. I suggest if the db gets slower with volume you investigate this. Like in the usual culprit... missing indices.

Comment: In this case, do you think it would be useful if I just migrate from ODBC driver to OleDB, or would it be a pure waste of time?

Comment: It would give you something, but it would be small 8I still would do it - odbc is not supported for a long long time). In the end, someone needs to lookat the reason why the db gets slower over size.